# Preserve quotes when converting array of string

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have

```
const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink']
```

How can I convert this array to a string:

```
""red", "yellow","pink""
```

I have tried: `colors.map(id => "'" + id + "'").join(', ')`

but this gives: `"'red', 'yellow', 'pink'"`

edit: I get answers with variations of what I've tried. Please note I need double quotes outside the string and between each word.

Comment: what about ```var x = '"'+colors.map(id => '"' + id + '"').join(', ')+'"';
console.log(x);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to achieve the desired result

```js
const colors = ["red", "yellow", "pink"];
let result = colors.join(", ").replace(/[a-z]+/gi, `"$&"`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this results in single quotes, i need double quotes. please look at original question i need it formatted exactly like that.

Comment: @tony code updated

Comment: i get '"red", "yellow", "pink"'

Comment: You won't get ` ""red", "yellow", "pink""`. Either you can get ` '"red", "yellow", "pink"'` or ` "'red', 'yellow', 'pink'"`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink'];
let result = colors.map(c => `"${c}"`).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: join it with `, ` with space also

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, i need an extra outer quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can put double quotes wrapped by single quotes, or escape the double quote inside of double quotes, or use ES6+ template literals (introduced in 2015):

```js
const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink']

console.log('"' + colors.map((str) => '"' + str + '"').join(", " + '"'));
console.log("\"" + colors.map((str) => "\"" + str + "\"").join(", ") + "\"");

console.log('"' + colors.map((str) => `"${str}"`).join(", ") + '"');
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, i need an extra outer quotes

Comment: @alli I've updated my answer to have extra outer quotes

Comment: sorry just found out what im looking for is not possible. when i convert to csv i get:

"\"\"red\"\"","\"\"yellow\", \"pink\"